# Logging to web service

Tags: logs

I like to log to a web service, that I can create so that I can implement filters/search/analytics and alerts more easily. Main thing I want to view logs for is that of my web application (NodeJS). How should I implement this? I can write a NodeJS module that will help do the logging but am thinking maybe its useful to just grab whatever is in stdout/stderr in cases where the server cannot even start.

Is it possible to log to a web service (eg. via curl or otherwise) every time something is written to logs? Will be great if it can be done in batches like every 5 seconds to reduce load.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source log monitoring project called [Log.io](http://logio.org/). If I'm understanding your question correctly, it does exactly what you want ("real time" web monitoring & analysis of server logs, with filtering capabilities), *and* it is based on node.js so it will likely integrate more easily with your project.

Another common log monitoring/analysis platform that you might be interested in looking at is [Nagios](https://www.nagios.com/solutions/web-log-monitoring/).

You probably don't need to write your own log monitoring application, and even if you decide to do so, looking at the above projects' code will probably provide you with some good examples of how to write your own log monitoring software.

Comment: I will say, though, that writing your own *could* make sense if it's only one or two log files you need to monitor AND you're fairly comfortable with some kind of scripting language (which is probably the case since you're writing web apps). There are plenty of examples of scripts online if you search for "FAVORITE_LANGUAGE log monitor". For example, with Python: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577968-log-watcher-tail-f-log/  ... if you wanted to use `curl` as you said, then in the linked example, you would just make the function `callback` make a `curl` request posting the new log data.